# How to pass "variable" to mysql JOIN (SELECT) subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need to count votes for each comment and there is a problem with this query.
Query takes about 3 sec for 1 M Comments and 3 M Comments

As I understand, problem is that mysql count all votes for all comments

```
SELECT com.*, cv.UC_Vote, cv.UC_Vote_Neg, cv.UC_Vote_Pos
    FROM Comments AS com
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT SUM(Vote) AS UC_Vote, SUM(IF(Vote < 0, Vote, 0)) AS UC_Vote_Neg, SUM(IF(Vote > 0, Vote, 0)) AS UC_Vote_Pos, UC_Code FROM CommentsVote
            GROUP BY UC_Code
        ) AS cv ON cv.UC_Code = com.UC_Code
    WHERE
       com.Blo_Code = $blocode AND com.UC_Status = 1
```

So how to pass UC_Code inside subquery like this?

```
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SUM(Vote) AS UC_Vote, SUM(IF(Vote < 0, Vote, 0)) AS UC_Vote_Neg, SUM(IF(Vote > 0, Vote, 0)) AS UC_Vote_Pos, UC_Code FROM CommentsVote
        **WHERE cv.UC_Code = com.UC_Code**
        GROUP BY UC_Code
    ) AS cv ON cv.UC_Code = com.UC_Code
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it!
Do like this

```
SELECT com.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(com.UC_Time) AS UC_UnixTime, com.UC_Code AS CommentId, com.UC_Parent AS ParentId, cc.UC_Complain,
                              (SELECT SUM(Vote) FROM CommentsVote WHERE UC_Code = com.UC_Code GROUP BY UC_Code) AS UC_Vote,
                              (SELECT SUM(IF(Vote < 0, Vote, 0)) FROM CommentsVote WHERE UC_Code = com.UC_Code GROUP BY UC_Code) AS UC_Vote_Neg,
                              (SELECT SUM(IF(Vote > 0, Vote, 0)) FROM CommentsVote WHERE UC_Code = com.UC_Code GROUP BY UC_Code) AS UC_Vote_Pos
                              FROM Comments AS com
                                LEFT JOIN (
                                  SELECT COUNT(us_id) AS UC_Complain, UC_Code FROM CommentsComplain
                                  GROUP BY UC_Code
                                ) AS cc ON cc.UC_Code = com.UC_Code
                              WHERE
                                com.Blo_Code = 473626 AND com.UC_Status = 1
```